# Does low-battery cause app crash on iPad?

Tags: ios, logging, crash

Today, I found a low battery log on my iPad, and I found my application was crashed.
I found these in same time.
So I doubt low battery cause application crash.

Was my app killed by battey being low?

Comment: Hi! Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User: https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Battery settings, Peak Performance Capability.

If the description is something like in the screenshot, then low battery can be cause of the crash.

[image]